# How to make install rule with a wildcard for files that don't exist in a pro file?

Tags: qt, qmake

Is there a way to set up installation to copy all files with a given extension, if these files are generated during build (so they don't exist when qmake is run)?
What I tried is basically this:

```
csmes.path = $$PATH_INSTALL_BIN
csmes.files = $$OUT_PWD/*.csmes
INSTALLS += csmes
```

but this doesn't work, the rule generated in a makefile is incorrect:

```
install_csmes: FORCE
     @if not exist install_release\bin mkdir install_release\bin & if not exist install_release\bin exit 1
    -$(QINSTALL) buld_folder\*.csmes install_release\bin\*.csmes
```

I also tried to use the [no_check_exist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#installs) option, but that only seems to work if the files are explicitly listed, which I'm really trying to avoid.

Is there a way to do this directly in a pro file? I can figure out some workaround and run a custom script during installation, I'm just wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: Did you try `csmes.files = $$files($$OUT_PWD/*.csmes)`?

Comment: Dud you try to do it by calling system commands from qmake? $$system(<command>). If you are using linux, use `find`.

Comment: @JarMan: `$$files` would run when qmake is run, so the files don't exist yet. I tried it anyway, but the makefile is exactly the same.

Comment: *"the rule generated in a makefile is incorrect"* -- Can you specify what the output actually is? And what you expect it to be?

Comment: @JarMan I've edited the question to add the makefile output. I don't expect it to be anything specific, just something that is a valid rule :) I don't care how qmake does it, that's the point of using it in the first place...

Comment: qmake runs before anything is built, so it won't be able to know what the actual filenames are. The best it can do is generate some sort of wildcard string for the Makefile to use. And that seems like what your output shows.